# Exception thrown in Global.asax.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

Exception thrown at `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); within Global.asax.cs` which is:

> "An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information:

> The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeConstants' threw an exception."

The inner exception is:

> {"Method not found: 'System.String System.String.Format(System.IFormatProvider, System.String, System.Object)'."}

I've reinstalled NuGet packages and references. Deleted contents of the bin folder. Cleaned and re-complied. Still no joy and always hits here.  It doesn't reach inside of WebApiConfig.Register. Any ideas?

Comment: That method is new to .NET 4.6: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906224(v=vs.110).aspx. Is 4.6 installed? You're using assemblies made for 4.6 which is probably a mistake.

Comment: I have the .Net framework 4.6 RC SDK and 4.6 RC Multi-Targeting Pack installed. Also switched target framework to 4.6 and still same error.

Comment: I've deleted all references to .NET 4.6 - made a fresh out of the box web api pointing at 4.5 and it occurs in that project too. Anyone have any more ideas

Comment: I have a feeling your machine might be hosed. Post the full exception ToString.

Comment: I'm getting this using VS 2013, on a machine where I just installed VS 2015 RC. My other development machine, where I have not installed VS 2015, does not exhibit this. Related, perhaps? I have not had time to investigate.

Comment: To loop back on this, I installed VS 2015 RC on that machine and the problem went away.

Comment: Sorry - that should have read * un-installed * VS 2015 RC

Comment: Yes I experienced the same problem once I installed VS 2015 RC. However, it didn't go away after uninstalling VS 2015. I manually removed all the extra stuff that came with it such as the SDK etc. Removing all ASP.NET temp files. Going through all the assembly references and double checking with Nuget release dates. Reinstalled 4.5 and No luck. It's like it got confused and picked up a new assembly. I had everything as the correct version. In the end I formatted my PC. worked fine after. You're lucky it went away after uninstalling. I had to go crazy and do the lot to eliminate it.